# Can I order my CSS columns horizontally instead of vertically? while using column-count

Tags: image-gallery, column-count

I want to order div row by row insated of filling column first then new column while using column-count.

**column-count:3**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaDBG.png)

It is giving output : 
1 5 9 
2 6 10 
3 7 11 
4 8 12

I want : 
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
10 11 12